# How to draw some targets like this?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to show some stimators properties in statistics. I'm very beginner in LaTeX, so I need some help.

[image: wanted]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: If you're a beginner, use `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package and draw your diagrams in whatever software you're familiar with.

Comment: As for statistical simulation, there are several example here about. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148091/gaussian-random-numbers

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I think i'm a beginner here too.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of diagram is quite easy to draw using [tikz/pgf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). It ha an extensive and well-written manual so by reading it you should get a good idea of what you need to do. Here is a similar example to get you started:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1];
    \draw[red] (0,0) circle[radius=2];
    \draw[blue] (0,0) circle[radius=3];
    \foreach \x in {-1,0,1} {
      \foreach \y in {-1,0,1} {
        \node[fill=white] at (\x,\y) {x};
      }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following picture:

[image]

If you wanted to draw `x`'s at a particular list of coordinates the easiest way to do this is with something like:

```
\foreach \x/\y in {-1/1,0/1,-1/0,-1/0,0/0,1/0,-1/-1,0/-1,-1/-1} {
    \node[fill=white] at (\x,\y) {x};
}
```

In fact, this is equivalent to the code in the example above.

Comment: Your nodes are not precisely centered on `x` (cf. [TikZ Nodes not exactly centered](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61343/14500)).

Answer (score 2):

You can also draw this sort of thing nicely in [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it), which you might enjoy learning. Here I've used the built-in `normaldeviate` command to generate some appropriate random target hits.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
beginfig(1);
numeric s;
picture target, cross;
s = 24;
target = image(for r=1 upto 3: draw fullcircle scaled (r*s); endfor);
cross  = image(draw (left--right) rotated 45; draw (left--right) rotated -45;);
picture A, B, C, D;
A = target shifted (-2s,+2s);
B = target shifted (+2s,+2s);
C = target shifted (-2s,-2s);
D = target shifted (+2s,-2s);

% mark "n" hits centered at "p" with "r" degree of scattering
vardef mark_hits(expr n, p, r) = 
  for i=1 upto n:
     draw cross shifted p shifted (r * normaldeviate, r * normaldeviate);
  endfor
enddef;

draw A; mark_hits(12, center A, 3); 
draw B; mark_hits(12, center B, 12);
draw C; mark_hits(12, center C shifted (-s/2,s/2), 3);
draw D; mark_hits(12, center D shifted (s/2,-s/2),12);

label.bot("(a)", 1/2[llcorner A, lrcorner A]);
label.bot("(b)", 1/2[llcorner B, lrcorner B]);
label.bot("(c)", 1/2[llcorner C, lrcorner C]);
label.bot("(d)", 1/2[llcorner D, lrcorner D]);

setbounds currentpicture to bbox currentpicture scaled 1.05;

endfig;


end
```

Comment: Very good. Thank you.It's exactly I was looking for.