# Replicating a bullseye plot using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to re-create the following graphic:

[image]

I know that this question has been asked before [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307117/reconstructing-the-following-bias-variance-diagram?noredirect=1&lq=1) but the solutions require compilation using `lualatex`.

I so far have the following:

[image]

I am trying to complete the graphic by adding the `Low Variance`, `High Variance`, `Low Bias` and `High Bias` titles/axis.

I am also trying to add the space between the `subfigure` plots. The vertical space seems fine but the horizontal space is too close.

Finally:

I would like to add two additional tags to the plot ( `overfitting` and `underfitting`) as in the following figure.

[image]

(Additionally: If I can add a black boarder around the points then this would be great and if I can make the colours darker as in the first figure also. I have tried a few ways to make the colours darker without luck)

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \r/\col in {2.8 cm/white,2 cm/blue!50!white,1.2 cm/white,0.4 cm/red!50!white}{%
    \path[draw,fill=\col] (0,0) circle (\r) ;}

    \foreach \coords in {(0,.1),(.1,.1),(.1,.2),(-.1,0),(-.2,.1),(-.1,-.1),(-.2,-.3),(-.3,-.1),(.3,-.1),(0,-.1),(-.1,0),(-.2,-.1),(-.2,-.2)}{%
    \draw[fill=blue] \coords circle (.6mm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \r/\col in {2.8 cm/white,2 cm/blue!50!white,1.2 cm/white,0.4 cm/red!50!white}{%
    \path[draw,fill=\col] (0,0) circle (\r) ;}

    \foreach \coords in {(0,.8),(.2,.9),(.8,.1),(-.1,.7),(-.1,-.4),(-.3,-.1),(-.4,-.9),(.2,-.9),(.5,.5),(-.5,.8),(-.7,-.8),(-.2,-.3),(-.5,0)}{%
    \draw[fill=blue] \coords circle (.6mm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\bigskip 
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \r/\col in {2.8 cm/white,2 cm/blue!50!white,1.2 cm/white,0.4 cm/red!50!white}{%
    \path[draw,fill=\col] (0,0) circle (\r) ;}

    \foreach \coords in {(0,1.2),(.1,1.4),(-.1,1.3),(-.2,1.2),(-.1,1.3),(-.1,1.4),(-.2,1.5),(0,1.3),(.3,1.4),(0,1.6),(.1,1.6),(-.2,1.5),(.2,1.7)}{%
    \draw[fill=blue] \coords circle (.6mm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \r/\col in {2.8 cm/white,2 cm/blue!50!white,1.2 cm/white,0.4 cm/red!50!white}{%
    \path[draw,fill=\col] (0,0) circle (\r) ;}

    \foreach \coords in {(0,1.3),(-1.3,0.4),(-1.4,2.0),(-1.2,1.0),(-1.0,1.6),(-.5,1.7),(-.2,1.5),(-.9,1.9),(.1,1.7),(-.9,1.6),(-.3,1.8),(-.6,1.7),(-.9,1.9)}{%
    \draw[fill=blue] \coords circle (.6mm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{}
\label{fig:biasVarianceTradeOff}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could draw the four bulleyes and tags in one tikzpicture (and thus just one figure) instead of four tikzpictures (and thus four subfigures). Is there a reason why you use that formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution without making many changes to your approach:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.40\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \r/\col in {2.8 cm/white,2 cm/blue,1.2 cm/white,0.4 cm/red}{%
    \path[draw,fill=\col] (0,0) circle (\r) node[align=center,above,text height=1cm,yshift=3cm]{Low\\Variance} node[align=center,left,text width=1cm,xshift=-3cm]{Low\\Bias};}

    \foreach \coords in {(0,.1),(.1,.1),(.1,.2),(-.1,0),(-.2,.1),(-.1,-.1),(-.2,-.3),(-.3,-.1),(.3,-.1),(0,-.1),(-.1,0),(-.2,-.1),(-.2,-.2)}{%
    \draw[fill=green] \coords circle (.6mm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.40\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \r/\col in {2.8 cm/white,2 cm/blue,1.2 cm/white,0.4 cm/red}{%
    \path[draw,fill=\col] (0,0) circle (\r) node[align=center,above,text height=1cm,yshift=3cm]{High\\Variance};}

    \foreach \coords in {(0,.8),(.2,.9),(.8,.1),(-.1,.7),(-.1,-.4),(-.3,-.1),(-.4,-.9),(.2,-.9),(.5,.5),(-.5,.8),(-.7,-.8),(-.2,-.3),(-.5,0)}{%
    \draw[fill=green] \coords circle (.6mm);}
    \node[red] (uf1) at (2.5,-2.5) {Overfitting};
    \coordinate (uf2) at (.5,-0.7);
    \draw [-latex,red,line width= 1.5pt] (uf1) -- (uf2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\par\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.40\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \r/\col in {2.8 cm/white,2 cm/blue,1.2 cm/white,0.4 cm/red}{%
    \path[draw,fill=\col] (0,0) circle (\r) node[align=center,left,text width=1cm,xshift=-3cm]{High\\Bias};}

    \foreach \coords in {(0,1.2),(.1,1.4),(-.1,1.3),(-.2,1.2),(-.1,1.3),(-.1,1.4),(-.2,1.5),(0,1.3),(.3,1.4),(0,1.6),(.1,1.6),(-.2,1.5),(.2,1.7)}{%
    \draw[fill=green] \coords circle (.6mm);}
    \node[red] (uf1) at (-2.5,2.5) {Underfitting};
    \coordinate (uf2) at (-.25,1.5);
    \draw [-latex,red,line width= 1.5pt] (uf1) -- (uf2);
    \node[red] (tr1) at (-2.5,-2.5) {Truth};
    \coordinate (tr2) at (-0.3,-0.3);
    \draw [-latex,red,line width= 1.5pt] (tr1) -- (tr2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.40\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \r/\col in {2.8 cm/white,2 cm/blue,1.2 cm/white,0.4 cm/red}{%
    \path[draw,fill=\col] (0,0) circle (\r) ;}

    \foreach \coords in {(0,1.3),(-1.3,0.4),(-1.4,2.0),(-1.2,1.0),(-1.0,1.6),(-.5,1.7),(-.2,1.5),(-.9,1.9),(.1,1.7),(-.9,1.6),(-.3,1.8),(-.6,1.7),(-.9,1.9)}{%
    \draw[fill=green] \coords circle (.6mm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Graphical illustration of bias and variance}
\label{fig:biasVarianceTradeOff}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```